# Trying to perform an update command on MySQL to insert a column of data is taking over 5 minutes. What can I do to debug this?

Tags: mysql

I have an application where it join two tables from two different MySQL DBs and with the resulting table from that join, update a column on another table in another DB.

The resulting data from the join isn't big. The result of the join is usually 25,000 rows and four columns. While I understand even inserting a column can take a while, currently it is taking over five minutes for mysql to perform an update command, which makes no sense. Worse part is that because I have a few of these queries to go through it can take over half an hour when doing this sequentially.

I'm using MySQL 8.0 on a Windows 10 machine and I've increased the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 1G

The queries vary in length, but a simpler one looks like:

```
Update resultOutput.resultTable result,
(
    select newConfigTable.tagName, newConfigTable.desc_1st_lang as newConfigDesc1, newConfigTable.desc_2nd_lang as newConfigDesc2, oldConfigTable.desc_1st_lang as oldConfigDesc1,oldConfigTable.desc_2nd_lang as oldConfigDesc2 from
    (
    select variable_id, desc_1st_lang, desc_2nd_lang, 
            fulLTagName as tagName
        from oldvarexpdb.common as common
        group by tagName 
        order by tagName asc
    ) as oldConfigTable
    right join
    (
        select variable_id, desc_1st_lang, desc_2nd_lang, 
            fulLTagName as tagName
        from newvarexpdb.common as common
        group by tagName 
        order by tagName asc    
    ) as newConfigTable
    on oldConfigTable.tagName = newConfigTable.tagName
) DescriptionTable
set result.`Description Test` = if(DescriptionTable.newConfigDesc1 =DescriptionTable.oldConfigDesc1 and DescriptionTable.newConfigDesc2 =DescriptionTable.oldConfigDesc2,'PASS','FAIL')
where result.tagName = DescriptionTable.tagName;
```

I can verify that everything in between the update call is working. Although it does take 150 seconds to display the entire table with 25,000 rows for some strange reason. That may or may not be related.

Any help would be amazing.

**Edit**:

Result of 'Explain Update' looks like:

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, PRIMARY, <derived4>, , ALL, , , , , 22216, 100.00, 
1, UPDATE, result, , ALL, , , , , 23100, 10.00, Using where
1, PRIMARY, <derived3>, , ALL, , , , , 22216, 100.00, Using where
4, DERIVED, common, , index, tagNameIndex, tagNameIndex, 1203, , 22216, 100.00, 
3, DERIVED, common, , index, tagNameIndex, tagNameIndex, 1203, , 22216, 100.00,
```

**Show Create Table**

For the table 'Common' (There are two of these table, but are created from the same create table command)

```
CREATE TABLE `common` (
  `variable_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fullTagName` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `variable_type` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `internal_id` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `1st_element` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `2nd_element` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `3rd_element` tinytext,
  `4th_element` tinytext,
  `5th_element` tinytext,
  `6th_element` tinytext,
  `7th_to_12th` tinytext,
  `desc_1st_lang` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `desc_2nd_lang` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `domain` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `nature` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `inhibit_flag` tinytext,
  `simulated_flag` tinytext,
  `permanent_flag` tinytext,
  `source` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `diffusion_indicator` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `station` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `reserved` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `subscription` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `object_root` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `extended_attribute` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `reserved2` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `remote_access` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `reserved3` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `reserved4` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `topology_server` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `topology_client` tinytext,
  `name_of_associated_label` tinytext,
  `binary_attributes` tinytext,
  `Text_attribute_3` tinytext,
  `Text_attribute_4` tinytext,
  `Text_attribute_5` tinytext,
  `Text_attribute_6` tinytext,
  `Text_attribute_7` tinytext,
  `Text_attribute_8` tinytext,
  `Text_attribute_9` tinytext,
  `Text_attribute_10` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `Text_attribute_11` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `Text_attribute_12` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `Text_attribute_13` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `Text_attribute_14` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `Text_attribute_15` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `Text_attribute_16` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `Visualization_level` tinytext,
  `is_initial_value` tinytext,
  `initial_value` tinytext,
  `reserved5` tinytext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`variable_id`),
  KEY `tagNameIndex` (`fullTagName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

For the table 'Result'

```
CREATE TABLE `resulttable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TagName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Tag Name Test` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description Test` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Digitals Test` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Units Test` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Analogs Minimum Ratio Test` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Analogs Maximum Ratio Test` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Type Test` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OPC DNP3 Source Test` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Commandable Range Test` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Internal Type Check Test` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Producer Test` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comment` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23877 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN UPDATE ....... - we may find you have no index on oldConfigTable.tagName OR no index on your newConfigTable.tagName

Comment: @WilsonHauck done. Please see edit.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (the 3 tables involved); for analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck. Please see edit